# CSS issue with image name @x2

Tags: css, image, retina

I discovered that for some reason CSS won't read image names that contains '@2x' (indicates that image is for retina), so for example, this will work:

```
#play { background: url(../images/layout/play_2.png) no-repeat; }
```

and this won't work:

```
#play { background: url(../images/layout/play@2x.png) no-repeat; }
```

It is the same i all browsers and across devices (iPhone, iPod, iPad). Any idea?

Comment: Try using `play\@2x.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percentage encode `%40` or escape `\@` the `@` character and it should work.

Your “some reason” is that `@` is a special character. See http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986 for more info on URLs

Comment: Yes my bad, thanks for pointing this out. I removed it from the answer. Quotes don't make `@` any less special.

Comment: It seems that the only way is to avoid using that '@2x' in image names. Thanx anyway!